# What's different about this variable assignment?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, variables

The following code attempts to put the contents of string c into arg[0].

```
const char **argv = new const char* [paramlist.size() + 2];
argv[0] = c.c_str();
```

This is another way to do it.

```
argv[0] = "someprogram"
```

I am noticing that later in my program, the second way works, but the first way causes an error. What could possibly be different? How could the first way be changed so that it works right?

This is where the problem occurs:

```
execvp(c.c_str(), (char **)argv);
```

If I change it to the following, then the problem doesn't occur. Why is that?

```
execvp(argv[0], (char **)argv);
```

Comment: Can you post the code that includes the declaration for the `c` variable?

Comment: @z_buffer: I ask because *where* you declare it with respect to the code you have in your question is actually rather important. Can you provide a code snippet that includes what you have in your question now, the `string c;` declaration, any code that modifies `c` in some way, and how you're accessing `argv`?

Comment: Probably it's because the `c_str()`-returned pointer is later invalidated by some change to the value of the `c` (i.e. you can't modify/clear `c` safely), or by `c` going out of scope / being `delete`d.

Comment: Why do you need to use raw arrays in C++? The `vector<string>` could be a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `_strdup`:

```
const char **argv = new const char* [paramlist.size() + 2];
argv[0] = _strdup(c.c_str());
```

`_strdup` allocates memory to store the copy of the string. When you are finished with the string, use `free()` to return the memory.

The `_strdup` function looks something like this:

```
char *_strdup (const char *s) {
    char *d = (char *)(malloc (strlen (s) + 1));
    if (d == NULL) return NULL;                  
    strcpy (d,s);                                
    return d;                                    
}
```

Comment: You might want to mention that if you do use _strdup, then it allocates memory to store the copy of the string in and that the caller is responsible for ensuring that this doesn't result in a memory leak.

Comment: 'strdup' fixes the problem. What are you supposed to do about managing its memory?

Comment: Yes I know:) but the question was just, How could the first way be changed so that it works right? of course you can use std::string and std::vector

Comment: If you're going to use `_strdup()`, at least mention that you need to `free()` the string afterwards.

Comment: What is _strdup? The POSIX standard mentions only strdup/strndup. C99 and C++ standards mention neither. I personally would not use non-compliant functions for such a trivial task.

Comment: I guess _strdup is visual studio

Answer (score 1):

In both ways you keep `const char*` pointers in `argv[0]`. So the only concern is whether pointers are valid and point to zero-terminated string.

"someprogram" pointer is valid and point to zero-terminated string during program execution.

`c.c_str()` pointer is guaranteed to be valid from the moment it is returned (by std::basic_string::c_str() function) to the moment string `c` is changed or destroyed. So if you access string `c` explicitly or implicitly with any non-const function (including its destructor) the pointer you stored into `argv[0]` will likely become invalid.

**ADD:**

Obviously to make `argv[0] = c.c_str();` variant work correctly you have to just use `argv` only in the scope of `std::string c` (where `c` exist) and don't change `c` in any way after you make this assignment (`argv[0] = c.c_str();`).